# C# creating a database class

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to create a class that handles all my Database-Stuff so i started with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Server
{
    class Database
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        public Database()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "mydb";
            uid = "root";
            password = string.Empty;

            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE = " + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            } catch(MySqlException e)
            {
                switch (e.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // Cannot connect to server
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        // Invalid username / password
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            } catch(MySqlException e)
            {
                // ex.message
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i don't know how i should handle inserts, updates and selects that they are dynamic to usw. I want to insert strings, dates and integers.. what is the best solution to create an insert, update and select function that can be used from everywhere?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to reinvent and not use a existing .netClass or framework ?

Comment: i prefer a existing .netClass but i couldn't find anything do you have a link?

Comment: DBContext class supports mysql in EF6 , take a look to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html, will be the easier approach I think

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

A) Make methods for every possible Select/Insert/Update/Delete within the Database class

or

B) Make a generic Select and Insert/Update/Delete method which takes an sql query (string) and array/list of SqlParameter and then this data is passed to the functions from another class

The Select method should return a DataTable and the Insert/Update/Delete method could return a value to determine success

Personally I much prefer option B.